# Akka: Dynamic configuration changes

Tags: java, scala, akka

I am currently reading up a bit on Akka, but there is one point I have not found anything so far yet. While I enjoy the powerful configuration options, f.ex. to configure Routers to dynamically resize and use given remote hosts, etc., I have not seen how to modify these configuration changes at runtime.

To make the question more specific: Let's say we have a router that is configured to route to three known remote hosts (say 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3). Now I add another machine to the system at 192.168.0.4. If I understand things correctly, it would need to run an Akka microkernel and then I could change the configuration to include this machine.

However, changing the configuration file seems to need a restart of the whole system (maybe I am mistaken there?). In that case, is there a way to dynamically modify the Router actor to include this new machine in its future routing, without disturbing its current operation (more than necessary at least) ?

Is there any kind of best-practice as to how to develop Akka systems that are re-configurable at runtime, i.e. without needing any downtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own router to do anything you want it to do.  [See this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html) for details on how to do that.  Alternatively you can wait for 2.2, which is supposed to have this feature built-in.

Comment: Actually 2.1 will ship with akka-cluster-experimental which contains cluster-aware routers; then you just add to the cluster and new routees will be created on the fly. (http://letitcrash.com/post/35055573978/2-1-spotlight-cluster-aware-routers)

Comment: @RolandKuhn Guess it depends on how brave he is... :)  I will say though that I've been quite impressed in the past with so-called experimental Akka builds.

Comment: The “experimental” in that package name is meant to signify that the API might still be optimized (and that it is not “officially” supported).